# How to find first occurence within a group when grouping by?

Tags: r, group-by, tidyverse

Here is an example of the input after being sorted on the date, the number of dates by id is unkown and gaps are possibe between dates:

```
input <-  tribble(
  
         ~id, ~date, ~outcome,
         
           1, "2000/01/01", FALSE,
           1, "2000/01/02", FALSE,
           1, "2000/01/03", TRUE,
           1, "2000/01/04", FALSE,
         
           2, "2000/01/01", TRUE,
           2, "2000/01/02", FALSE,
           2, "2000/01/03", TRUE,
           2, "2000/01/04", FALSE,
         
           3, "2000/01/01", FALSE,
           3, "2000/01/02", FALSE,
           3, "2000/01/03", FALSE,
           3, "2000/01/04", TRUE
         )
```

I want to keep all the lines once the outcome has been true.
Here is the desired output:

```
output <-  tribble(
  
         ~id, ~date, ~outcome,
         
           1, "2000/01/03", TRUE,
           1, "2000/01/04", FALSE,
         
           2, "2000/01/01", TRUE,
           2, "2000/01/02", FALSE,
           2, "2000/01/03", TRUE,
           2, "2000/01/04", FALSE,
         
           3, "2000/01/04", TRUE
         )
```

I have tried tidyverse constructs with `group_by()` but with no success:

```
input %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  ???
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After grouping by 'id', `filter` by doing the `cumsum` on the logical column (`TRUE` -> 1 and `FALSE` -> 0) so that with `cumsum` at the first TRUE value, it changes value to 1 and continues until it hit another TRUE value, thus if we do `> 0`, it will only return rows from the first occurence of TRUE

```
library(dplyr)
input %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    filter(cumsum(outcome) > 0) %>%
    ungroup
```

-ouptut

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
     id date       outcome
  <dbl> <chr>      <lgl>  
1     1 2000/01/03 TRUE   
2     1 2000/01/04 FALSE  
3     2 2000/01/01 TRUE   
4     2 2000/01/02 FALSE  
5     2 2000/01/03 TRUE   
6     2 2000/01/04 FALSE  
7     3 2000/01/04 TRUE
```

---

Another option is also to `match` which returns the index of the first TRUE value and get the sequence after that

```
input %>%
     group_by(id) %>%
     filter(row_number() >= match(TRUE, outcome))
```

#### data

```
 input <-  tribble(
  
         ~id, ~date, ~outcome,
         
           1, "2000/01/01", FALSE,
           1, "2000/01/02", FALSE,
           1, "2000/01/03", TRUE,
           1, "2000/01/04", FALSE,
         
           2, "2000/01/01", TRUE,
           2, "2000/01/02", FALSE,
           2, "2000/01/03", TRUE,
           2, "2000/01/04", FALSE,
         
           3, "2000/01/01", FALSE,
           3, "2000/01/02", FALSE,
           3, "2000/01/03", FALSE,
           3, "2000/01/04", TRUE
         )
```

Comment: Is there something missing from this (or maybe I am)? When I run this code, I just get the same output as the original tibble `input`, which is a 12x3.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
library(tidyverse)

input <- input %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(id, date) %>% ## if not orderd already
  mutate(outcome2 = replace(outcome, which(outcome == T)[1]:n(), T)) %>% 
  filter(outcome2 == TRUE) %>% 
  select(-outcome2) %>% 
  ungroup()
```